# Not able to fetch JSON value using variable

Tags: javascript, axios, dialogflow-es

I am using dialogflow to fetch JSON value based on a variable. I want to provide Country as a variable, and wish to fetch JSON result under it. The Key parameter after the Country is not fetching the expected result.

Here is code:

```
  axios({
   "method":"GET",
    "url":"https://coronavirus-map.p.rapidapi.com/v1/summary/latest",
    "headers":{
    "content-type":"application/octet-stream",
    "x-rapidapi-host":"coronavirus-map.p.rapidapi.com",
    "x-rapidapi-key":"b69dXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX70148c1179"
    }
    })
    .then((response)=>{
      console.log(response.data);   //Works OK
      console.log("--myCountry from Variable--"+ myCountry);   //variable Works Ok
      console.log("--Total cases Response: Status--" + response.data.status);   //Status OK
      console.log("--Total Cases Response: Hardcoding Country variable--" + response.data.data.regions.india.total_cases);   //Total cases OK
      console.log("--Total Cases Response: System Input myCountry variable--" + response.data.data.regions[myCountry].total_cases);   // NOT OK!
})
```

Attached is the error screenshot:*TypeError: Cannot read property 'total_cases' of undefined at axios.then*
[Log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Blx5d.png)

Here is JSON response.data:[JSON response object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tVAdV.png)

How can I fetch the 'total cases' under the Country using a variable?

[JSON Data is accessed from endpoint.](https://rapidapi.com/Yatko/api/coronavirus-map?endpoint=apiendpoint_6692b41d-76da-4791-a0a7-d8b9d392bb21)

Sample data:

```
{
   "status":200,
   "type":"stack",
   "data":{
      "summary":{
         "total_cases":2243360,
         "active_cases":1518967,
         "deaths":153412,
         "recovered":570981,
         "death_ratio":0.06838492261607589,
         "recovery_ratio":0.25452045146565866
      },
      "change":{
         "total_cases":-18077,
         "active_cases":-14572,
         "deaths":-918,
         "recovered":-2587,
         "death_ratio":0.00014070444860095344,
         "recovery_ratio":0.000890569227064375
      },
      "generated_on":1587157203,
      "regions":{
         "india":{
            "name":"india",
            "total_cases":698851,
            "active_cases":602681,
            "deaths":36842,
            "recovered":59328,
            "death_ratio":0.052717961339398524,
            "recovery_ratio":0.08489363254828282
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Actually, the following request results in UNDEFINED error:
response.data.data.regions[myCountry]

so anything following that also becomes undefinded (as shown in the main question)

Comment: Please edit your question to add data example, so we can test.

Comment: The error is saying that `response.data.data.regions[myCountry]` is undefined. Are you sure `response.data.data.regions` has ` key of the specified country?

Comment: Yes nick, myCountry Key was there in JSON. But my variable had India, but JSON key had india as country name. when i changed the variable toLowerCase it worked.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found the ANSWER, Variable should have been in small letters:

```
var myCountry=(agent.parameters['geo-country']).toLowerCase()
```

Result log [image shows india count now sowing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7dSJ.png)